# How to print name in a pyramid scheme using two loops?

Tags: java

I've tried just about everything I can think of. I'm supposed to have the user enter a name, and their name will be displayed like:

```
"b
 ii
 lll"
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = console.next().toLowerCase(); 
    printPyramid(name);
}

public static void  printPyramid(String name) {


    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {

        System.out.println(name.charAt(i));


        {
            for (int j =1; j<=i ; j++)
            System.out.print(name.charAt(j));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The letter is supposed to be printed as many times as the number of the line that it's on. Since 'I' is on line two, it got printed twice. Since 'L' is on line three, it gets printed three times. I'm just bad with these nested loops.

Comment: If my name is bill then l will be print firstly 3 times and 2ndly 4 time ??

Comment: There's no other way to get better than to debug it yourself.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi: b will print on a line by itself just one time. 'i' will print on line 2 and will print twice. 'l' will print on line 3, and will print 3 times. every letter prints on a new line.

Comment: @PM77-1 : if you do not have anything useful to say, please stay out of my topic. i've already tried to play with the code. that's why i am here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loops as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void  printPyramid(String name) {


    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {

    System.out.println();

    {
        for (int j =0; j<=i ; j++)
            System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
    }


}
```

}
print `i` instead of `j`

Input :`pravin`

output:

`p
rr
aaa
vvvv
iiiii
nnnnnn`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this here should do the job:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        System.out.println("Enter yor name:"); 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//Scan the name
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length();i++) //For every letter on it
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= i;j++) //Lets print it i+1 times (1,2,3,4... etc)
            {
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i)); //Get the letter in that position.
            }
            System.out.println(); //Change Line
        }
    }
}
```